# Cin taking invalid number of inputs

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I assign the variable `arrSize` with zero ( `int arrSize = 0;`  ) and in next line I take input from user for the variable `arrSize`. Let's suppose the user assigns `5 value` to the variable.
When I execute my code, `Cin` is taking only `4 values` instead of `5`.
But when I only declare the variable `( int arrSize; )` and don't assign any value to it, then it's working perfectly fine. 
 I'm a newbie, can you please explain why is it happening?
Thank You!

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int arrSize = 0;
    int arr[arrSize];
    cout << "Enter the array size: ";
    cin >> arrSize;

    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Output: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++){
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }


}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: `int arr[arrSize];` declares a zero element VLA -- neither are part of C++. What you see is *Undefined Behavior*. Instead `#include <vector>` and then `std::vector<int> arr{};` Then loop `int tmp; for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) if (cin >> tmp) arr.push_back(tmp);` Then to output `for (const auto& a : arr) std::cout << a << '\n';`

Comment: When you define the array `arr`, what is the value of `arrSize`? The definition of `arr` will be done in the order you write it in the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Value of `arrSize` is `0` when I define the array and in the next line I'm asking the user to input the value for `arrSize`.

Comment: @Aetooc -- C++ programs run top-down.  Setting `arrSize` to something else after you've declared the array doesn't magically make the array bigger.  It's a moot point anyway -- the program doesn't use standard C++.  As pointed out, use `std::vector`.

Comment: [C++17 Standard (latest draft) - \[dcl.array\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array) *"Its value N specifies the array bound, i.e., the number of elements in the array; N shall be greater than zero."*

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you declare `arr[arrSize]` before reading `arrSize`.
So you actually declare your array `arr` to be `arr[0]`.

This type of arrays is called variable sized or variable length arrays. Actually it is a nonstandard feature and should be avoided if you want to write a cross-platform code. This feature is supported by at least GCC compilers.

The better way is to make the array dynamic and initialize it with `new` keyword. As other answers mentioned, the cross-platform way of writing it would be `int* arr = new int[arrSize];`

Comment: So should I ask the user to enter the value `arrSize` before declaring `arr[arrSize]`?

Comment: @Aetooc Exactly. Just declare your array after reading its length

Comment: To my knowledge as of C++20 Variable Length Arrays are still not in Standard C++. There are a lot of good reasons for this, my personal favorites are if you don't know how much automatic storage you need or, god forbid, you let the user decide, you're just asking for stack overflows, and it makes a total hash of the compile-time nature of `sizeof`.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't have purchased standard unfortunately. But I guess you are right. Here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf a constant expression is mentioned instead of just expression. I'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

That is not how arrays are declared and that’s why it’s causing undefined behaviour.
You have to mention the number of elements the array will hold during initialisation itself.

So you have 2 options

1. Static array : Here you need to specify size of the array in code and cannot be decided during run time

> int arr[5];

2. Dynamic array: Their size can be decided at runtime

> int *arr= new int[arrSize];

Where arrSize is the value of the array size you read from user input.
Also intialise the array after you have read the arrSize input from user (i.e. after cin)

Comment: Prefer [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to a manually managed dynamic array. YOu will have fewer memory management headaches.

Comment: @user4581301 True. Vectors are a saviour from the memory management headaches. However the intent here is to just demonstrate basic array functionality, since he is simply trying to create a array when size is taken as input from the user during run time.

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried compiling the exact code you wrote and I got some errors popping up. Maybe this won't answer your question, but this might be helpful a bit, at least from my knowledge.

A few days ago, I tried to do something similar and do something like "int arr[arrSize];", which isn't necessarily a good habit. You are supposed to allocate memory dynamically in that case, or at least put a constant (not a variable) inside the square brackets.

Example:

```
int arr[5]; // <-- this will allocate you 5 elements, indexed from 0 to 4
```

Or the other that I prefer to use dynamically (using pointers, similar with normal vectors, but a lot more powerful in my opinion):

```
int* arr = new int[arrSize]; // <-- this allocates you arrSize elements indexed from 0 to arrSize - 1
```

I would change the 4 lines into:

```
int arrSize;
cout << "Enter the array size: ";
cin >> arrSize;
int* arr = new int[arrSize];
```

Probably now you understand as well that, when you do declare int arr[5], let's say, you will allocate memory for only 5 elements. I don't know exactly why, but I suppose it's a convention for indexation. In Matlab for instance, the first element is indexed at 1, meanwhile, in C/C++ it starts at 0

Comment: Recommendation, when you go reaching for `new` to make a dynamic array, slap your hand and reach for a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: "when you do declare int `arr[5]`..." you reserve storage for `5` integers on the stack. (the array has *automatic storage duration*) With `int* arr = new int[arrSize];` you allocate storage for `arrSize` number of integers. (`arr` has *allocated storage duration*)